# O que é Tuple e quando usar?

Tags: c#, .net, estrutura-de-dados, tuple

Vi o uso em um site e fiquei com a duvida de o que é `Tuple`, e quando devo utilizar em meu projeto?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

O termo significa vasilha. Ele serve para por coisas diversas dentro. [Formalmente é uma lista de elementos finitos ordenados](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

O .NET a disponibilizou para agrupar alguns dados que precisam ser armazenados, e principalmente transportados juntos, sem que tenha uma semântica específica. Ou seja, é uma forma de criar uma estrutura de dados com tipos heterogêneos, assim como acontece com uma classe ou `struct`, mas sem criar um tipo.

Ele não deve ser abusado, sempre que fizer sentido é melhor criar um tipo. Sempre que isto der maior robustez, significado e organizar melhor o que está fazendo, deve criar um tipo. A tupla deve ser considerada para casos "emergenciais", coisas que não se propagarão.

Um dos maiores usos <strike>é</strike>era para retornar mais de um valor em um método. Então você encapsula estes valores dentro da tupla.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). Note que existem variações para permitir que vários valores sejam encapsulados. Dependendo da quantidade necessária, tem que usar um tipo diferente adequado para acomodar todos os membros.

Uma alternativa às tuplas são os [tipos anônimos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Exemplo:

```
Tuple<int, string, decimal>(1, "exemplo", 10.00m);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Tuple.cs).

Note que os membros não possuem nomes, um dos motivos que ela deve ser evitada, falta semântica. Os membros podem ser acessados por campos genéricos nomeados de `ItemX`, onde X é o número do item na ordem.

Duas tuplas podem ser consideradas compatíveis se elas tiverem o mesmo número de elementos, dos mesmos tipos, na mesma ordem.

O [C# 7 tem isso na linguagem](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347) de forma bem melhor, ainda que a forma antiga pode continuar tendo alguma utilidade em raros casos. O novo mecanismo tem semântica de valor e não gera alocação no *heap*, portanto é mais eficiente. A tupla antiga de biblioteca ainda pode ser útil quando precisa de um temp ode vida maior (quase sempre é um erro).

- [Como retornar 2 ou mais valores de uma vez em um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101)

Comment: Complementando a resposta, uma tupla é um grupo de valores que só fazem sentido juntos. Por exemplo, um par de coordenadas ou um vetor, ou latitude/longitude, em que os números isolados não servem para muita coisa. Por isso as linguagens de programação asseguram que uma tupla não pode ter elementos manipulados.