# Tuplas em banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, tupla

Eu sei o que é uma tupla em Python mas não em banco de dados, portanto segue a pergunta:

O que é uma tupla no contexto de banco de dados?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tupla é uma vasilha (tradução literal) onde coloca uma porção de coisas. A grosso modo referimos ela como sendo a **linha** da tabela, ou o registro, como também é conhecido o conceito. Mas vamos ser mais específicos.

Pela definição matemática é uma sequência ordenada e finita de elementos. Cada elemento possui um nome identificador (nem toda tupla precisa ter um) e um valor.

Note que [ordenada não é classificada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

Então no banco de dados seria você juntar os dados necessários para preencher o que a tabela espera em apenas uma unidade conceitual.

No momento do `INSERT` vemos a tupla de forma bastante clara. Exemplo:

```
INSERT (id, nome, idade, salario) VALUES (1, "joão", 25, 1000.00);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/Tuple.sql).

Aí temos uma tupla formada pelos nomes `(id, nome, idade, salario)` e outra com os valores `(1, "joão", 25, 1000.00)`, assim como está acostumado em Python e outras linguagens.

Note que para o contexto, sem os nomes não é uma tupla, é apenas uma linha, embora seja comum as pessoas usarem o termo intercambiavelmente, na definição de alguns, no contexto de banco de dados.

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94882/101).