# Ordenar dicionário pelo valor Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, classificação, dicionário

Tenho um dicionário com o seguinte formato

```
dic={759147': 54, '186398060': 8, '199846203': 42, '191725321': 10, '158947719': 4}
```

gostaria de saber sé há como ordená-lo pelo valor e imprimir na tela. De modo que a saída seja.

```
'158947719': 4
'186398060': 8    
'191725321': 10
'199846203': 42
'759147': 54
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar a função [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
dic = {'759147': 54, '186398060': 8, '199846203': 42, '191725321': 10, '158947719': 4}
for item in sorted(dic, key = dic.get):
    print (dic[item])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3B0FRl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/abbqpgvh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/SortedCollection.py).

Só um detalhe, o termo mais correto seria [classificar o dicionário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

Answer (score 3):

Um dicionário em python não tem ordem, na maior parte dos casos não tem sentido manter a ordem dos itens do dicionário.

Porém existe o [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) ([também em python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)).

Alternativamente você pode ordenar uma lista com as chaves e acessar os valores na ordem dessa lista.