# Percorrer dicionário Python a partir do final

Tags: python, dicionário

Gostaria de saber se há como percorrer as chaves de um dicionário de trás pra frente? Por exemplo, em um dicionário `d1 ={1: [], 2: [], 3: [], ..}` começar pela chave 3. Sei que é possível percorrer a partir do início com `for`, mas preciso começar pela última chave ou uma específica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como, mas é preciso entender que não é possível ordenar um dicionário.

[Como ordenar um dicionario que leva uma tupla com chave](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233096/5878)

[Ordenar dicionário pelo valor Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172147/5878)

[Ordenar dicionário pelo valor e usar regra caso o valor seja o primeiro python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/235961/5878)

[Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/5878)

Porém, para acessar os índices na ordem desejada, você precisa gerar uma lista com todos os índices, ordená-la e percorrê-la acessando a respectiva posição no dicionário. Em Python, isso ficaria algo como:

```
# Dicionário:
dicionario = {1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c"}

# Gera a lista com os índices:
indices = list(dicionario.keys())

# Ordena a lista de índices em ordem reversa:
indices = reversed(indices)

# Percorre a lista de índices, acessando a respectiva posição:
for indice in indices:
    print(dicionario[indice])
```

A saída será:

```
c
b
a
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/g994wn).

De forma simplificada, o mesmo pode ser feito com:

```
for indice in sorted(dicionario, reverse=True):
    print(dicionario[indice])
```

Pois, ao iterar sobre um dicionário, apenas seu índice é considerado. Assim, a função `sorted` retorna a lista de índices ordenado de forma reversa.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/w0Zo3C).

Comment: Da para usar a OrderedDict do modulo collections