# Como ordenar um dicionario que leva uma tupla com chave

Tags: python-3.x, dicionário

Eu possuo um dicionario da seguinte maneira:

```
dicionario = {(0,0,0):['alguma informacao']}
```

como eu posso ordenar este dicionario a partir de uma das informaçoes da chave? 
Por exemplo:

```
dicionario = {(0,0,0):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,1):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,2):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,5):['alguma informacao'],(0,1,0):['alguma informacao']}
```

viraria

```
dicionario = {(0,0,0):['alguma informacao'],(0,1,0):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,1):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,2):['alguma informacao'],(0,0,5):['alguma informacao']}
```

se ordenado a partir do terceiro item da chave.

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, uma leitura que possivelmente será interessante:

[Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168531/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ordered-unordered-e-sorted)

Não faz muito sentido você desejar ordenar um dicionário, pois a própria implementação do mesmo não garante uma ordem - um dicionário representa uma tabela *hash* e nem faz muito sentido você desejar ordená-lo. Mas se a necessidade é acessar em ordem os valores do dicionário, alternativamente você pode converter os índices do dicionário para uma lista, ordená-la (o que agora faz sentido, pois é uma lista) e acessar os respectivos valores no dicionário seguindo a lista ordenada. Algo como:

```
dicionario = {
    (0,0,0): ['0, 0, 0'],
    (0,0,1): ['0, 0, 1'],
    (0,0,2): ['0, 0, 2'],
    (0,0,5): ['0, 0, 5'],
    (0,1,0): ['0, 1, 0']
}

indices = sorted(dicionario.keys(), key = lambda item: item[2])
```

Isso gerará em `indices` uma lista de tuplas ordenada com base no terceiro valor. Desta forma, basta percorrer a lista ordenada, acessando os respectivos valores no dicionário:

```
for i in indices:
    print(i, dicionario[i])
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nAOkam).

Ou, se realmente precisar ter os valores armazenados em um dicionário, a partir da versão 3.1 do Python, a biblioteca `collections` possui a implementação da classe `OrderedDict`, que armazena os valores na ordem que forem inseridos. Então, de forma semelhante a anterior, basta converter o dicionário para uma lista, ordená-la e convertê-la em um `OrderedDict`. Algo como:

```
novo_dicionario = OrderedDict(sorted(dicionario.items(), key = lambda item: item[0][2]))
```

Assim, para percorrer este novo dicionário, basta fazer:

```
for key, value in novo_dicionario.items():
    print(key, value)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/M6el1U).

Perceba que enquanto a condição for somente o terceiro valor da tupla, não é garantido a ordem dos valores cujo este terceiro valor seja igual entre si.