# Ordenar dicionário pelo valor e usar regra caso o valor seja o primeiro python

Tags: python, classificação

Quero fazer um dicionário em python no qual vai ter doenças e pontuações
ex:
dic['alzhelmer']=3
dic['gripe']=5

O programa deve colocar em ordem as enfermidades das que mais pontuaram para as que menos pontuaram (decrescente) no dicionário
ex:

dic['gripe']=5
dic['alzhelmer']=3

E por fim caso por exemplo gripe for a que mais pontuar, dar um comando.

ex:
if dic['gripe'] == maiorpontuador:

```
    "url= gripe.com"
```

Desde já muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233096/5878

Answer (score 1):

Dicionários em python não são "ordenáveis". Há vários outros objetos ordenáveis em python, então sugiro que use um deles e depois transfira para um dicionário do tipo OrderedDict (que, diferente de um dicionário comum, mantem a ordem em que foi criado sempre que acessá-lo), exemplo:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Criando pontuações em lista de tuplas (poderia ser lista de listas)
data = [('Asma', 6), ('Cachumba', 5), ('Difteria', 4),('Rubeola', 9)]

# Criando o dicionario
od = OrderedDict([par for index, par in sorted((tpl[1], tpl) for tpl in data)])

print (od)
OrderedDict([('Difteria', 4), ('Cachumba', 5), ('Asma', 6), ('Rubeola', 9)])

print(od['Cachumba'])
5
```

> Editada
>   Se vc quiser pela ordem reversa:

```
# Criando pontuações em lista de tuplas (poderia ser lista de listas)
data = [('Asma', 6), ('Cachumba', 5), ('Difteria', 4),('Rubeola', 9)]

# Criando a indexação na ordem reversa
dr = sorted([(tpl[1], tpl) for tpl in data], reverse=True)

# Criando o dicionário
od = OrderedDict([tpl[1] for tpl in dr])

print (od)
OrderedDict([('Rubeola', 9), ('Asma', 6), ('Cachumba', 5), ('Difteria', 4)])
```

Obs.:
Se sua lista ja está ordenada, então é só criar o dicionário (OrderedDict) normalmente. Quanto a questão do "comando" no final da pergunta, não consegui entender, a finalidade dos dicionários é somente mapear chaves/valores.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!