# Qual algoritmo de ordenação o .NET utiliza por padrão em uma lista?

Tags: c#, .net, classificação, lista

Estou com um problema que tenho que realizar ordenação em memória de um número elevado de itens e gostaria de saber qual o algoritmo que o .NET utiliza para ordenar quando chamamos o método `Sort()` de uma lista, por exemplo.

Necessito saber pois percebi que meus dados vêm com uma certa ordenação, então precisa de poucas trocas, e dependendo do caso posso obter melhores resultados aplicando algoritmos diferentes.

Comment: Qual `Sort()` Da classe `Array`?

Comment: Estou utilizando uma lista, não sei se é o mesmo, seria: minhaLista.sort() e eu passando o meu comparer como parâmetro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ele usa um algoritmo de [classificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

O [`Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-8.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort) da classe `List<T>` usa o algoritmo do *array*, já que internamente a lista é só um *array*. Segundo a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-8.0#overloads) ele usa um algoritmo introspectivo e se adapta conforme o que trará melhor resultado. Então ele pode optar por usar:

- [Insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) - se tiver menos de 16 elementos
- [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) - se as partições do *array* superam 2 * LogN, onde N é o tamanho da faixa que será ordenada
- [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) - demais casos

É possível acessar os fontes e ver o [algoritmo utilizado](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,78c62950ae211cd3). Se quiser acompanhar como chegou nisso tem o [fonte do método público que chama](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Array.cs,78c62950ae211cd3).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).