# Tipos de ordenação e seu desempenho, qual escolher?

Tags: php, desempenho, classificação

Eu conheço diversas formas de ordenação como *Selection Sort*, *Bubble Sort* e *Quicksort*, também temos as funções do PHP como `sort()` e `array_multisort()`.

Atualmente o sistema que eu desenvolvi trabalha com o *Bubble Sort* porque é o mais simples, porém pelo que eu vi ele é mais demorado, e agora trabalhando na atualização do sistema implementei o uso do `array_multisort()`, mas me veio a dúvida de como essa função trabalha e se não seria melhor eu criar um *Quicksort*, atualmente meu sistema trabalha com poucos dados então está indiferente o método escolhido mas pensando no futuro e na sua manutenção qual seria a melhor escolha?

O que eu estou ordenando? É um *array* que possui as distancias de um ponto X a N pontos e agora usando o `array_multisort()` depois de ordenar pela distancia eu ordeno pelo tempo.

Comment: Mas a intenção é saber qual o ponto mais proximo de `X` ? Isso é informação que muda ou é "fixa" ?

Comment: @Isac o problema da pergunta não é a ordenação isso eu estou fazendo tranquilamente a minha duvida é a respeito de qual seria a melhor forma de se fazer para uma manutenção e desempenho melhorado

Comment: Eu faço a pergunta porque saber os `N` pontos mais próximos de `X` ou pontos a `Y` de raio de distancia de `X` não implica ordenação, e será mais eficiente sem ordenar.

Comment: @Isac eu trabalho com a informação ja calculada pela API do Google, que me retorna um json com os dados e então eu crio alguns arrays 2 deles um sendo distancia e o outro tempo, e assim eu os ordeno do menor para o maior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos usar a [terminologia correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101). Você quer classificar e não ordenar, já está em uma ordem, não está classificado.

A [documentação do PHP faz uma comparação do que tem pronto para uso](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Dependendo do que precisa o [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) é uma péssima ideia. Mas não sabemos do que precisa. Inclusive a quantidade de trabalho pode determinar se ele é útil ou não. Por exemplo, [o .NET se adapta de acordo com os dados da coleção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245366/101).

Posso te garantir que algum deles deve usar um Quicksort muito mais otimizado do que você poderá fazer. De fato [a documentação fala que a maioria das funções usam este algoritmo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Talvez fazer um *benchmark* com cada um seja o caminho a seguir. Mas faça com vários tamanhos e várias distribuições dos dados. Descarte antecipadamente os que não atendem a semântica que você precisa. Se nenhum te atender comece pensar em fazer um próprio, mas não faça em PHP que tem muito [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101).

Pode ser que a solução seja outra bem diferente do que está pensando e nem seja o caso de classificar nada, mas estou só especulando.

[Respondi sobre alguns algoritmos conhecidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118131/101).

Complemento: [Por que usar um ponteiro nesse algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/255626/101)

Comment: Eu estava lendo os links que você colocou na resposta ajudou bastante, vou tentar fazer o *benchmark* , achei bem interessante o metodo do .NET , o objetivo final do meu sistema é informar os usuários mais proximos de quem procura usando uma API do Google (Matrix) , então eu preciso classificar aqueles que estão mais perto e menos tempo , mas obrigado ai pela resposta vou me aprofundar nas opções que eu for encontrando até decidir qual a melhor vai me servir