# Por que não se deve iterar um hashmap?

Tags: java, desempenho, lista-encadeada, hashmap, iterator

Estive a fazer um projeto e um dos meus colegas mencionou que iterar *hashmaps* é algo que se deve evitar e ao invés de usar *hashmap* deveria usar *linked lists*.

Contudo penso que a versatilidade do *hashmap* de poder guardar strings como chave permite fazer coisas do tipo:

```
hash_distrito->hash_cidade->array_coordenadas(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Seu colega provavelmente está considerando essas estruturas de dados de maneira abstrata. Uma lista ligada, conceitualmente, é uma estrutura adequada para iteração, mas potencialmente lenta para acesso a itens específicos. Já o HashMap é mais eficiente que a lista ligada para acesso a itens específicos, o que não quer dizer que seja lento de iterar. Na verdade vai depender da implementação. Numa pesquisa rápida, não achei referências a evitar a iteração de hashmaps.

Comment: Obrigado mas caso eu pertende-se iterrar a estrutura dada como exemplo. Teria de criar uma linkedlist para obter os dados? ou o tempo de iteração do hashmap é desprezável?

Comment: Por que não simplesmente [pegar a lista de chaves](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) e iterar com um for normal ou Iterator? Parece que você está preocupado com microotimizações.

Comment: So gostaria de saber todas as possiveis soluções para determinar se são relevantes ou não. So poderei saber se a opção x é melhor ao fim de compreender porque que as outras y e z não sao tao boas. Paravalem disso e eu gostaria da compreender o ponto de vista do meu colega.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando alguém disser o que deve fazer, peça justificativa.

## Iteração

Iterar qualquer estrutura de dados com um conjunto de dados não tem problema algum, na forma geral.

Se quer iterar de forma específica, em uma estrutura específica, e quer um resultado específico, aí pode ter um problema.

Essencialmente todas as estruturas de dados básicas podem ser iteradas em [complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101) linear O(n). Só não seria assim alguma estrutura bem complexa e muito específica que praticamente ninguém usa. Em geral não consegue fazer em menos tempo que isso, e não levará mais. Tanto que ninguém coloca qual é a complexidade para este algoritmo, ela é "sempre" igual.

Você quer iterar em alguma ordem específica? Precisa ser na ordem que os elementos foram inseridos? Ou precisa uma classificação específica? Se precisar de algo assim é melhor usar outra estrutura, se puder. Mapas geralmente não possuem ordem definida. Até existem implementações que permitem ordem, mas só podem ser usados em circunstâncias específicas, a maioria dos mapas usam tabelas de espalhamento, que não permitem [ordem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

## Alternativas

Se precisa da ordem use um *array* ou estrutura baseada nele. É ótimo na imensa maioria das necessidades.

Se precisa dos dados classificados então deve ser mais interessante usar uma árvore, que é uma lista ligada que tem mais de um caminho para seguir na sequência.

É muito raro a lista ligada pura ser útil, em geral só quando ela não precisa ser manipulada depois de criada, a não ser na(s) ponta(s) e também não precisa de acesso aleatório, o que faz com que outras estruturas também sejam adequadas.

Listas ligadas, como se aprende no curso de computação, essencialmente não são usadas no "mundo real". Implementações mais sofisticadas, provavelmente combinadas com outras estruturas, podem ser úteis em certos cenários.

É muito comum as pessoas acharem que inserir e remover um elemento de uma lista ligada pode ser feito em complexidade constante, porque a operação em si realmente é constante. Porém quase sempre precisa chegar no ponto onde o elemento será inserido ou removido, e aí a complexidade é linear.

Eu devo ser uma das poucas pessoas que usam lista ligada em banco de dados em certa circunstância. Usei onde me deu alguma vantagem sobre o índice normal que o DB já possui. Embora hoje é raro eu ter esta necessidade. Tem que pesar tudo para decidir qual é a melhor estrutura.

## Não avalie errado

Eu já vi gente transformar um *array* em mapa para poder indexar em tempo constante em vez de linear. Não digo que isto seja inútil em todos os casos, mas quase sempre a complexidade passou ser O(n + k) no melhor caso, ou seja só desvantagem. A pessoa esquece de contar o tempo da cópia da estrutura. Se tivesse feito no *array* seria O(n) no pior caso e O(1) no melhor.

Talvez o seu problema seja mais adequado para uma lista ligada, mas não sabemos ao certo qual seria esse problema. Pode ser que precise o uso conjunto de mais de uma estrutura, e uma delas seja uma lista ligada (talvez não tradicional).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Eu devo ser uma das poucas pessoas que usam lista ligada em banco de dados em certa circunstância". Atiçou minha curiosidade :)

Comment: Nos bancos modernos é menos necessário a não ser para otimização extrema. Nos mais antigos também costuma ser para otimização. Se você tem um dado que pode ter uma tamanho indefinido, pode ter várias instâncias dele e a normalização conceitual não é necessária (o dado nunca será acessado de forma independente do seu dono), uma forma é normalizar fisicamente só para atender a demanda do mecanismo, aí precisa de um índice na tabela para acessar rapidamente, o que ocupa espaço e custa para fazer atualizações. A lista ligada aí elimina a necessidade do índice (no fundo é um índice que eu controlo)

Comment: Claro que só é útil em banco de dados cujas tabelas sejam estruturadas como um *array* (hj os DBs costumam ser listas ligadas, mesmo que em forma de árvore), e precise iterar toda a lista de forma direta e ainda não tenha muitos elementos.

Comment: Entendi. Nesse caso o que você está chamando de lista ligada no bd é implementado como chave estrangeira + índice?

Comment: Não, é o oposto, não tem índice, só a lista, ele funciona como um índice, mas não é. A questão é que hoje nos DBs toda tabela é um índice, por isso não precisa nada, antes tinham DBs que ñ era assim, então precisa de uma tabela + índice para acessar rápido o que quer. Desta forma precisa só da tabela, ou seja, eu faço em DB antigo o q os novos fazem internamente. Faço isso em NF, os itens são LL cujo header está na NF e o footer é 0. E os itens fazem o mesmo c/ as linhas de descrição dele. Tem app q precisa os itens normalizados conceitualmente, aí a LL ñ ajuda (mas ajuda c/ a descrição)

Comment: Cada item é uma linha e cada um tem uma coluna apontando para o próximo ou NULL, é isso? Eu quis dizer algo assim quando falei em FK, não necessariamente uma chave formal no banco.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Entendi.