# O que significa "ordenar uma matriz", seja por linhas ou colunas?

Tags: c, terminologia, matriz, classificação

O que significa "ordenar uma matriz", seja por linhas ou colunas?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente um jeito errado de dizer "classificar cada elemento de uma linha ou de uma coluna de uma matriz". Veja [Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101). Todo mundo fala errado. Em ordem já está, não está classificado. Você não pode ordenar algo que já possui uma ordem. Em inglês você diria *sorting a matrix*, não diria *ordering a matrix*.

Então você pega uma sequência de valores, provavelmente números, que está em um ordem qualquer, analisa cada um deles, vai trazendo para o começo os valores menores, e vai mandando para o fim os valores maiores, assim no final cada elemento seguinte sempre será maior que o anterior, seno o primeiro o menor de todos e o último o maior de todos. Também é possível classificar de forma descendente e o primeiro é o maior e o último o menor.

Se não for números a classificação de ser lexicográfica, ou seja, popularmente de forma alfabética. Se for outro tipo de dado tem que determinar como classifica.

Uma coisa que pode acontecer é usar mais de um elemento como critério, então teria que adotar um critério, pode ser só olhar o primeiro elemento da linha ou coluna, a soma, ou outra coisa.