# O que é o sort do Java?

Tags: java, string, lista, classificação

Todo programador saber que uma lista de *arrays* são impressas de forma ordenada, porém no meio do caminho tem `sort()`.

O resultado da impressão foi essa:

```
Abacaxi
Banana
Laranja
Manga
```

Eu imaginava que fosse imprimir dessa forma:

```
 Banana 
 Laranja 
 Manga 
 Abacaxi
```

Eu não sei como o `sort()` se comporta, mas pelo que estou vendo ele imprime seguindo a ordem alfabética quando se trata de *strings*?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("Banana", "Laranja", "Manga", "Abacaxi");

        Collections.sort(fruits);
        for (String fruit : fruits) {
            System.out.println(fruit);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explique porque você acha que deveria ser esse resultado, não faz o menor sentido o que você está perguntando. Você quer saber o que a função `sort()` faz? É isso? Se for, não poderia perguntar de forma mais simples?

Comment: @Maniero eu só queria saber porque ele imprimiu assim  Abacaxi Banana Laranja Manga invés de assim  Banana Laranja Manga Abacaxi . de fato eu não sei como o ´sort´ se comporta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `sort()` classifica listas de dados. Na sua forma mais simples usa uma ordem crescente. Se os dados são textos é claro que a ordem é alfabética.

Toda lista tem alguma ordem, pode ser uma ordem natural ou pode ser uma ordem adaptada. A função `sort()` muda a ordem classificando cada elemento pela ordem alfabética.

É óbvio que se você aplica uma função a uma lista é provável que essa lista seja modificada de alguma forma. Não faria sentido usar a função e esperar que tudo fique igual.

Então após a chamada desta função, que pode ser bem demorada se a lista for muito grande, a lista terá uma nova ordem "definitiva". Claro que a lista não manterá sempre tudo em ordem alfabética se for manipulando os dados, a estrutura da lista não é naturalmente classificada, então futuras manipulações não serão classificadas, se precisar da classificação terá que executar `sort()` novamente. Se precisa sempre fazer isso é melhor usar outro tipo de estrutura que seja automaticamente classificada, que não é o caso do `ArrayList`.

[Documentação da função `sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)).

Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre ordered, unordered e sorted?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Julgo que está a confundir os termos *"ordered"* e *"sorted"*.

O Array representa um conjunto de elementos com uma determinada ordem(*ordered*) mas não necessariamente ordenada/classificada(*sorted*) pelo menos, neste caso, por ordem alfabética.

Ele é *"ordered"* porque os itens mantêm uma ordem/sequência que advém da sua posição(indice) no array.