# Adicionando um objeto à uma coleção retorna "cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface

O código é esse:

```
public class Catalogo {
SortedSet<Produto> lProdutos = new TreeSet();

public void addProduto(int cod, String desc, float preco){
   try{
   Produto p = new Produto(cod, desc, preco);
   lProdutos.add(p);
   }
   catch (Exception e){
       System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
   }
 }  
}
```

Ao executar, considerando **cod = 5**, **desc = "x"** e **float = 5** caio nessa exceção:

> catalogo.Produto cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É isso mesmo que a mensagem de erro está dizendo, você não implementou a interface [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) na sua classe `Produto`. Para que um objeto seja colocado em uma coleção `SortedSet` este tipo precisa ser capaz de entregar se um objeto dele é maior ou menor ou igual a outro objeto, afinal esta coleção precisa estar classificada ([*sorted*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101)) e a classificação exige saber essa característica.

Então o erro está na classe `Produto` e não neste trecho de código, ou com os dados usados, deveria ser algo como (a grosso modo):

```
class Produto implements Comparable<Produto> {
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Produto outro) {
        return String.compare(this.nome, outro.nome);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/ImplmentsComparable.java).

Inventei um critério, em geral alfabético do nome geral dele não será muito bom, mas pode ser o que deseja.