# Média, Minimo e máximo num dicionário em python

Tags: python, dicionário

Eu tenho um dicionário desse género:

```
{walt: 0.942342, disney: 0.324234, robert: 0.562354, help: 0.546912, ...}
```

E faço isso para encontrar a média e o máximo:

```
media = statistics.mean(dicContadores.values())
counter = collections.Counter(dicContadores.keys())
maximo = counter.most_common(1)
minimo = min(dicContadores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

print("   Média: ", media)
print("   Máximo: ", maximo)
print("   Minimo: ", minimo)
```

Do jeito que esta tenho este output:

```
 Média: 0.0714285
 Máximo: [('walt', 1)]
 Minimo: ('disney', 0.324234)
```

Mas tenho 1 problemas:
Como faço para que no máximo o valor associado não seja arredondado?

Comment: Vc editou e colocou [resolvido], não seria interessante compartilhar a solução?

Comment: A solução já foi colocada, quando coloquei [resolvido]

Comment: @Walt057 O SOpt utiliza a estrutura de perguntas e respostas, separando muito bem o que é cada coisa. A pergunta é para perguntar, a resposta para responder. Se você possui a solução para o seu problema, publique sempre como **resposta**.  Leia sobre [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878). Além disso, é desnecessário adicionar "[resolvido]" no título. Isso é limitação que fóruns alheios possuem, mas o SOpt não.  Quanto a isso leia sobre [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/5878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dicionários define uma relação injetora entre as chaves e os valores, um mapa, então não faz sentido serem ordenáveis ([ou melhor, classificáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/5878)).

Para poder classificar o máximo e mínimo, você precisará criar uma outra estrutura que seja classificável. Você já fez isso na pergunta quando utilizou `dicContadores.items()`, que retorna um iterável contendo tuplas de dois valores sendo a chave e o valor, respectivamente.

Mas você pode, também, fazer isso de forma implícita através somente do parâmetro `key` de `max()` e `min()`. Quando utilizado, você implicitamente criará em memória outra estrutura que será utilizada para a classificação de valores.

```
maximo = max(dicContadores, key=dicContadores.get)
minimo = min(dicContadores, key=dicContadores.get)
```

Assim, `maximo` e `minimo` serão as **chaves** onde ocorrem os valores máximos e mínimos dentro do dicionário.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={"a": 3, "b": 2}
minimo = min(d, key=d.get)
print(minimo)
maximo = max(d, key=d.get)
print(maximo) código aqui
```

Agora esta certo, realmente me equivoquei.