# Estrutura de dados em C# pra vizinho-mais-próximo?

Tags: c#, estrutura-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Atualmente tô botando todas as posições num vetor ordenado. Quando quero o vizinho mais próximo, passo pelo vetor todo.

Quero saber se existe uma estrutura em algum *namespace* do C# pra isso. Tipo uma *hash* que quando não encontra um valor, retorna o mais próximo.

Comment: como assim "vizinho mais próximo"? se não encontrar um valor ele não está no array, como pode ele ter um vizinho? faria sentido se encontrasse o valor, ai sim ele teria ao menos um vizinho (antes ou depois), vc quer dizer o valor mais próximo (maior ou menor) de um valor que não foi encontrado?

Comment: Sim, o mais próximo, caso o valor não esteja no array (o que quase sempre é o caso)

Comment: e quais valores tem nesse vetor? valores simples, numeros, strings ou são objetos?

Comment: Objetos. Fiz uma classe que armazena informações de um dado ponto no espaço. Daí caso um ponto X não esteja no vetor (que quase sempre é o caso), eu procuro o elemento no vetor que tenha o ponto mais próximo

Comment: então precisa colocar essa classe  na sua pergunta pra ajudar. Se fosse um tipo simples, uma lista de inteiros por exemplo, poderia fazer isso com o próprio `OrderBy`, ou `Aggregate`, agora como é um objeto, vai ter de escrever sua própria lógica para fazer isso, usando IComparer` por exemplo, mas só vendo o que tem no seu objeto pra dar um exemplo mais acertivo, o resto seria só palpites

Comment: Eu desconheço listas fuzzy em C#. Mas o algorítimo eu sei o nome, ele se chama **Distancia Levenshtein** ele mede quantas transformações que uma string precisa para se igualar a outra. Tudo o que tem que fazer é percorrer uma lista aplicando esse algorítimo a string que apresentar o meno coeficiente de transformação é a string mais próxima.

Answer (score 1):

Não foi dada muita informação então não posso ajudar com algo mais detalhado, mas não existe estrutura de dados adequada para isto.

De fato para sua descrição precisa de estrutura de dados classificada ([ordenado é um termo errado aí](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101)), então pode fazer isso manualmente toda vez antes de fazer a busca (ou uma vez se puder garantir a imutabilidade da coleção de dados), ou pode usar uma estrutura que se auto classifica como o [`SortedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), sem isso só analisando toda coleção. Mas para achar o próximo é algoritmo e não estrutura de dados. Se não souber fazer tem chance de ter pronto usando LINQ (provavelmente [`Aggregate()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) ou pelo menos na biblioteca [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ), aí é achar um método que supra sua necessidade.

Depois em comentário foi dito algo sobre espaço, se for isso aí o problema é bem mais complexo e se isto for clarificado fica amplo demais.