# Quais as diferenças entre as implementações da classe Set no Dart?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, dart

A documentação diz que `Set` é *Uma coleção de objetos em que cada objeto pode ocorrer apenas uma vez.*

Na documentação desta classe tem um pequeno resumo das diferentes classes que implementam `Set`:

*A iteração sobre os elementos de um conjunto pode ser ordenada ou desordenada Exemplos:*

*Um `HashSet` não é ordenado, o que significa que sua ordem de iteração não é especificada,
`LinkedHashSet` itera na ordem de inserção de seus elementos e
um conjunto de elementos `SplayTreeSet` repete os elementos na ordem de classificação.*

A grosso modo parece que a diferença se resume a ordenação e repetição de elementos.

Qual a diferença prática entre eles para obter a melhor utilização de cada?

[*Baseado nesta pergunta*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930950/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-map-implementations-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não conheço as implementações específicas de Dart, sei o que estas estruturas são no geral. A pergunta do SOen *linkada* pouco tem a ver com esta porque lá é sobre mapas e aqui sobre conjuntos. Ela ajuda para explicar os motivos diferentes, até porque imagino que o que muda de lá pra cá é a unicidade do valor.

Todas elas são um *set*, ou seja, um conjunto de dados que não se repetem. A diferença entre elas é a implementação interna e por isso existem compromissos diferentes de performance em cada tipo de operação ou até mesmo de consumo de memória, por isso cada uma pode ser mais adequada do que outra em cada cenário. Todas armazenam as mesmas coisas e podem fazer essencialmente o mesmo (tem exceção).

Por não conhecer a implementação interna vou falar presumivelmente, mas se a estrutura tem um nome de uma coisa universalmente conhecida e na verdade implementar outra, a tecnologia é muito ruim.

## HashSet

É basicamente uma *hash table* que garante que os valores não se repetem. Qualquer tipo de tabela *hash* não pode garantir [ordem dos dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168531/101), seja por chave ou valor. Ela tem compromissos de performance O(1), ou seja, constante, leva o mesmo tempo não importa o tamanho da estrutura. Só lembrando que o fato de não ter ordem impede acessar o dado de forma direta.

## LinkedHashSet

Já foi questionado que o nome disto está errado (*hash* também deve estar porque indica o detalhe de implementação para garantir certa característica, isto é ruim porque depois ou não pode mudar ou fica esquisito chamar uma coisa e ser outra, de fato eu acho que a equipe que cuida de Dart muito fraca, cada resposta que eu dou eu vejo um problema, não chega ser um PHP, mas pra algo que começou recentemente não podia cometer os mesmos erros).

Pelo que pude entender é uma estrutura que mantém essas duas estruturas internas, ou seja, tem uma tabela *hash* por isso consegue manter as mesmas características da estrutura acima, mas consegue dar ordem (a mesma da inserção) porque também tem uma lista ligada. O compromisso ruim é que ocupa mais memória por ter duas estruturas internas.

A complexidade de algoritmo depende de alguns detalhes de implementação, em condições simples normais é o mesmo da estrutura anterior, ou seja, O(1), mas há casos que é O(N) já que existem operações que só podem ser feitas corretamente na estrutura de lista ligada (ex.: inserção no meio da lista).

Tenho minhas dúvidas se não deveria usar um *array* no lugar de uma lista ligada, só não garanto porque não vi todas discussões do porquê terem adotado isto, mas parece outro erro.

## SplayTreeSet

Como pode-se imaginar ela implementa uma estrutura chamada [*splay tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) e que obviamente é uma árvore montada de uma forma específica para ter mais performance nos itens que são acessados com mais frequência. A documentação é péssima e a resposta *linkada* só copiou o que está na Wikipedia sem entender o que é isto. Eu imagino que ela te fornece os dados classificados quando quer isto (leia o que eu já *linkei* antes para entender as diferenças), se não fornecer isto a estrutura estaria muito errada. Eles poderiam ter optado por qualquer outra árvore e todas oferecem praticamente todas operações em complexidade logarítmica O(logN), esta foi escolhida porque ela permite uma otimização para acessar mais rápido os itens mais frequentemente acessados. Até onde eu sei o ganho é irrisório e muitas pessoas questionam se vale o esforço adicional de fazer isto, inclusive porque tem alguns compromissos.

Novamente é uma pena o nome dizer como é implementada internamente.

Pelo que li o *default*, ou seja a `Map` e a `Set` usa a estrutura de dados mais custosa em memória e a diferença não é pequena, pra mim outro erro.

Imagino que aqui não aceite valores `null`, ou pelo menos aceite só um elemento com este valor, a documentação não fala nada, teria que investigar internamente.

Então realmente a diferença tem a ver com ordem e classificação, além de compromissos de performance e consumo de memória que não foram citados na resposta do SOen. O mapa tem os mesmos compromissos mas aceita valores repetidos.