# Existe alguma diferença de binary search para ordered binary search em uma lista?

Tags: python, algoritmo, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou estudando algoritmos de *searching* e queria entender melhor a diferença de *binary search* para *ordered binary search*. Eu entendi que, para ambos os algoritmos funcionarem, a lista precisa estar *sorted*. Pelo que li nessa [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168531/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ordered-unordered-e-sorted), isso significa que uma lista sempre terá um sequência definida baseada nos valores dos elementos. Dessa forma, o código abaixo (retirado de uma [página](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/data-structures-and-algorithms/index.php) de exercícios sobre o assunto) funciona com a linha `lista.sort()`, mas deixa de funcionar (para ambas as funções) se tiro ela:

```py
def Ordered_binary_Search(olist, item):
    
    if len(olist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(olist) // 2
        if olist[midpoint] == item:
            return True
        else:
            if item < olist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(olist[:midpoint], item)
            else:
                return binarySearch(olist[midpoint+1:], item)


def binarySearch(alist, item):

    first = 0
    last = len(alist) - 1
    found = False

    while first <= last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last) // 2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < alist[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint - 1
            else:
                first = midpoint + 1

    return found

lista=[0, 19, 52, 3, 1, 8, 14, 18, 34]
lista.sort()
print(binarySearch(lista, 3))
print(Ordered_binary_Search(lista, 3))
```

Ocorre que me parece que as duas funções estão fazendo, essencialmente, a mesma coisa. O que significa *ordered* nesse caso? Existe alguma diferença de binary search para ordered binary search?

Comment: Acho que na verdade é a mesma coisa e, nesse caso, a diferença é a implementação — veja que o primeiro usa recursão e o segundo, não. Talvez o `ordered` no nome tenha sido usado para evitar uma colisão de nomes. Até onde eu sei, para que um _binary search_ funcione, os valores a ele passados devem estar em ordem (_ordered_). Então nem faria sentido criar um _unordered binary search_.

Comment: Para uma binary search funcionar em uma lista a lista precisa estar tanto ordered quanto sorted? Eu entendi o porquê da lista precisar estar sorted, mas não entendi bem o que significa estar ordered nesse caso e por que isso é necessário para o algoritmo funcionar.

Comment: Se você quer levar a diferença entre "ordered" e "sorted" ao pé da letra (como explica [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168532/69296)), creio que a lista deve estar _sorted_, uma vez que o critério de comparação (que fora usado para _sortear_ a lista) será utilizado no próprio _binary search_ para navegar entre os "braços" da "árvore binária". No caso do seu algoritmo, note que está sendo utilizado o operador `<`. Ele exige que a lista esteja ordenada em um critério previamente estabelecido (no caso, do menor para o maior em comparação numérica). Em suma, _sorted_.

Comment: Existe "busca binária", e só. Pra mim só parece uma escolha infeliz de nome, pois a função `Ordered_binary_Search` deveria se chamar `recursive_binary_search` pois é isso que ela faz: a mesma coisa que a função `binarySearch`, mas com recursão em vez de iteração. Como o algoritmo é o mesmo, e o pré-requisito da busca binária é que os elementos estejam ordenados, isso explica pq só funciona se vc ordenar a lista antes.