# O que é "expressão idiomática" na programação?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem

Já me deparei com o termo "expressão idiomática" ou "forma mais idiomática". Basta pesquisar no site que irá achar várias referências: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=idiomatica

Afinal o que é "expressão idiomática"? Tem relação com [programação elegante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173216/o-que-%C3%A9-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-elegante)?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_idiom%C3%A1tica

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tem relação com programação elegante sim. Não é elegante produzir códigos não idiomáticos. Mas elegância não é tudo em programação.

A expressão ou forma idiomática é o jeito mais elegante de se fazer uma tarefa comum naquela linguagem.

Vamos pegar o inglês.

> Eu separei da minha namorada

Poderia ser traduzido como:

> I splited with my girlfriend

Isso pode ser entendido, mas não é idiomático. Ficaria melhor falar:

> I broke up with my girlfriend

Em programação é assim também, você pode fazer algo que funciona bem, o código executa e produz o resultado esperado sempre, provavelmente de forma eficiente, mas naquela linguagem específica tem um jeito mais elegante de fazer, talvez gere até mais eficiência ou evite algum problema que só existe nessa linguagem.

Um idioma pode se aproximar de um padrão de projeto (*design pattern*), mas não chega ser porque ele é algo mais específico. Algumas pessoas poderão confundir com boas práticas, e em certo sentido é, pelo menos na forma de escrever o código para uma tarefa bem simples. Também poderia ser confundido com uma receita de bolo, mas idioma é mais sobre a forma de escrita do que a tarefa em si.

Idioma aqui significa um jeito específico de usar uma linguagem. É a forma peculiar de expressar algo em determinada linguagem.

Códigos não idiomáticos costumam ser produzidos quando é pego uma solução de uma linguagem e porta na outra. Ou se o programador experiente em outra linguagem não está acostumado com o padrão daquela linguagem. Ou ainda se ele está produzindo códigos, mas não é programador de verdade. Mesmo linguagens parecidas, como Java e C#, possuem idiomas muito diferentes.

Algumas linguagens se beneficiam bastante de códigos idiomáticos, outras ocorre mais pela estética, é conformação com aquela comunidade específica.

## C#

Por exemplo, você pode programar em C# de forma 100% imperativa, abandonar OOP. Mas não é idiomático.

Ou pode abusar de `dynamic` ou `object` pra flexibilizar a aplicação, mas não é idiomático.

Pode preferir varrer coleções com `for` no lugar de um `foreach` ou mesmo LINQ, mas não é idiomático.

Pode usar o padrão de projeto [Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101) e não um `event` que é o idiomático.

Note que escrever de um jeito ruim vai além de não ser idiomático. Se em vez de usar `using` para dispor de recursos, usar um `try-finally` não é idiomático, mas se nem usar o `try-finally`, aí já é erro mesmo.

Você pode criar um [padrão de nomenclatura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) seu, mas a linguagem tem um padrão que é mais idiomático.

C# tem uma forma idiomática moderna e outra forma legada. E isso muda em cada versão. Por exemplo, em C# 7 [tuplas](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347) substituíram em muitos casos pelo menos o uso de [`Tuple<>`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94882/101) e [`out`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101) em parâmetros.

## Python

Um exemplo não idiomático em Python:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newlist = []
for i in mylist:
    newlist.append(i * 2)
```

Agora idiomático, dito jeito *pythônico*:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
newlist = [(i * 2) for i in mylist]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Pythonic.py).

## Idiomas universais

Tem idiomas que não são tão inerentes à linguagem. Um exemplo é a tal da [*fluent interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101).

## Conclusão

Nem sempre as pessoas concordam qual é o jeito idiomático. E a mesma linguagem pode ter jeitos diferentes. Muitas vezes existe o jeito idiomático legado e o jeito moderno com o advento de alguma forma nova de expressar aquilo mais elegantemente. E alguns domínios podem exigir um idioma específico.

Um dicionário de idiomas de uma linguagem poderia agrupar as mais diversas formas de escrever o código de certas tarefas que são comuns para um programador. Sinto falta disto na internet.

Programadores profissionais procuram fazer do jeito idiomático até onde faz sentido. Programadores amadores fazem na base do bumba-meu-boi. Programadores profissionais não usam os idiomas sem questioná-los antes e sabe quando evitar o idioma em favor de uma solução melhor para aquele caso. O profissional sabe qual idioma usar.

Tem um [artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom) sobre o assunto.

Comment: Não aceitei ainda pra ver se vai ter outra resposta. Ótima resposta.

Comment: @Murilo é sempre bom esperar mesmo, não tenha pressa alguma. Eu mesmo gostaria que tivesse outras respostas.