# sprintf() não dá o resultado esperado

Tags: c, c++, string, variáveis, int

Eu possuo variáveis do tipo `Unsigned Long Int` e gostaria de salva seu valor em uma `string`, para efetuar calculo de *checksum* e enviar via comunicação serial.

```
void Payload(int long unsigned lastTime, float deltaOne, float deltaTwo, int factor){

[...]
sprintf(buffer, "CAPTION,%u,%s,%s,%d," lastTime,deltaOne,deltaTwo,factor);
SendWithCS(buffer);
}
```

Porém o valor convertido de `int` para `string` não é o mesmo.
Exemplo:

```
int long unsigned record = 11285600;
float delta1 = 50.2035;
float delta2 = 54.2035
int factor = 5;
Payload(record,delta1,delta2,factor);
```

Saída:

```
CAPTION,22601,50.2035,54.2035,5,3F
```

Comment: Por que o primeiro é um ponteiro? Você vai enviar esse valor ou o ponteiro? Como pode sair 5 dados se você só está usando 4? Esse código nem compila, tem muitos erros.

Comment: ops, digitei errado rs

Comment: Tem outros erros, veja tudo. Leia o comentário todo acima.

Comment: Esse código é parte de um outro código bem maior, porém como as outras partes não são de relevancia só coloquei um fragmento dele, o ultimo valor de saida é dado pela Função SendWithCS;

A Saída da string do sprintf para a variavel buffer seria 

CAPTION,22601,50.2035,54.2035,5,

Comment: Por que deve mostrar 22601 se o que está passando é 11285600?

Comment: Essa é a pergunta, porque está mostrando 22601 se estou passando 11285600?

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, porque isso parecia ser o que você espera. Na verdade eu usei seu código, tem muito erro nele, e não gera isso não, certamente o código que você está executando é diferente deste postado.

Comment: Esse código não vai compilar, ele depende de outras funções, somente é cabível de explanação a parte do sprintf , a unica duvida é do porque eu entro com a variável na função e a string do buffer se apresenta com um valor que difere do formato original.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

O código tem vários erros, depois de arrumá-los o que sobrou foi a formatação errada. [Veja as opções existentes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Este é um código C compilado com C++. Estas funções são evitadas em [código idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101) C++.

O número sem sinal estava errado, e os de ponto flutuante também.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Payload(unsigned long lastTime, float deltaOne, float deltaTwo, int factor) {
    char buffer[sizeof(unsigned long) + sizeof(float) + sizeof(float) + sizeof(int) + 13];
    sprintf(buffer, "CAPTION,%u,%.4f,%.4f,%d,", lastTime, deltaOne, deltaTwo, factor);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    printf("\nCAPTION,11285600,50.2035,54.2035,5,\n");
}

int main() {
    unsigned long record = 11285600UL;
    float delta1 = 50.2035;
    float delta2 = 54.2035;
    int factor = 5;
    Payload(record, delta1, delta2, factor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kVBHKi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kgwfzyaa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Sprintf.cpp).