# O que são antipadrões de projeto de software?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Existe um catálogo deles para consulta, assim como existe para os padrões de projeto? Antipadrões são o mesmo que más práticas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É uma maneira de resolver um problema que foi considerada ineficiente, ineficaz, inefetivo ou improdutiva. Existe em diversos campos.

Curiosamente alguns padrões de projeto conhecidos na computação são considerados antipadrões por alguns.

Ele tem o mesmo problema dos padrões, as pessoas vão atrás deles como se aquilo fosse uma receita para adotar em todos os casos causando mais problema do que solução. Então já podemos começar citando o *antipattern* que é seguir padrões e antipadrões **cegamente**, bem como boas práticas ou más práticas.

A questão é como e onde é usado. O contexto define de fato se aquilo é bom ou ruim. Inclusive há controvérsia do que é realmente um *antipattern* estabelecido ou não, Em geral isso ocorre porque não há contexto.

E de fato os *antipatterns* normalmente definidos existem de forma muito informal e não passa pelo mesmo crivo que os *patterns* mais conhecidos.

No caso dos antipadrões eles se parecem muito com más práticas, já que eles não costumam definir fórmulas prontas de solução do problema e sim apenas recomendações. Em caso de código eles são *code smells*.

Assim como é uma bobagem seguir padrões conhecidos como se fossem fórmulas mágicas, juntar um monte de antipadrões por si só não vale muito. Na verdade, pode ser pior, porque a pessoa pode achar que se não está ali não tem problema fazer algo. As pessoas são muito criativas para fazer coisas erradas.

E é preciso entender que tanto o *pattern*, quanto o *antipattern* é só uma regra de como fazer algo que pessoas consideraram como boas ou ruins. É uma boa dica, mas é preciso aprofundar-se e entender sua motivação para usar corretamente.

Eu costumo dizer que *pattern* é tudo o que é executado sempre do mesmo jeito para resolver o mesmo problema. Ao contrário do que as pessoas pensam não é só um conjunto com algumas receitas de bolo que as pessoas ouviram falar por aí.

Um exemplo que cito muito é a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), que é um *pattern* tão usado que está pronto para uso sem que você se dê conta que ele é um padrão de projeto.

E como existem padrões, as linguagens ou outras tecnologias acabam criando antíteses aos padrões de projeto. Ou elas decidem não adotar algo porque consideram um *antipattern*. Por exemplo, Java não queria criar um mecanismo de delegados, relutaram por anos dizendo que era um *antipattern*, até que perceberam que era só um *pattern*, e dos mais importantes, e botaram na linguagem. Percebe que muitas vezes o *antipattern* está carregado de desinformação e preconceito? E não estou falando de gente boba, falei de um grupo de pessoas dos mais inteligentes do mundo. Preconceito existe em todo mundo, inclusive nas pessoas que são contra preconceitos.

E existe a recursividade que é um *antipattern* em vários contextos, mas muita gente usa porque acha engraçadinho.

Outro exemplo: as pessoas dizem que usar `goto` é um anti-padrão, mas as atrocidades que acabam fazendo em alguns casos onde ele é útil só para dizer que não usaram um *antipattern*, é claramente um *antipattern*.

Fazer códigos piores para atender uma regra estabelecida por alguém que sequer entendia do que estava falando ou que o que ela falou virou "telefone sem fio" é o maior antipadrão que existe.

Existe um [site que tem uma lista de alguns](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns).

A [Wikipedia traz uma lista que me parece mais interessante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Tem uma [resposta no SO com uma lista específica bem útil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27567960/221800).

Foram publicados [alguns livros sobre o assunto](http://antipatterns.com/).

Podem existir outros mais específicos, inclusive para linguagens e paradigmas, talvez mostrando o que não é [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101), como o [Pitfalls of Object Oriented Programming](http://www.objectsbydesign.com/books/pitfalls.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Antipadrões Javeiros: http://antipadroesjava.blogspot.com/