# Método equivalente a BigInteger.and() no C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, operadores, biginteger

Preciso converter o código java abaixo para C#:

```
public static boolean verificaPermissao(BigInteger perm1, BigInteger perm) {

    if (perm1 == null || perm == null || (perm1.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || (perm.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))))
        return false;

    return !perm.and(perm1).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);
}
```

Porem não sei qual a função em C# para o `and`

```
public static bool verificaPermissao(BigInteger perm1, BigInteger perm)
{
    if (perm1 == null || perm == null || (perm1.IsZero) || (perm.IsZero ))
        return false;

    //Converter para C#
    //return !perm.and(perm1).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);Converter para C#
}
```

O método `and` não existe no `BigInteger` do C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O [`and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#and(java.math.BigInteger)) é a mesma coisa que usar o operador `&` ([*bitwise and*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_bitwiseand(v=vs.110).aspx)) entre os dois valores e isto é igual nas duas linguagens.

Fiz outras adaptações também. No C#, `BigInteger` é um tipo por valor, ou seja, ele nunca será `null` e a verificação do zero já é feita no `return`.

```
public static bool VerificaPermissao(BigInteger perm1, BigInteger perm) 
{        
    return (perm & perm1) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito! achei que o and do java fazia mais comaprações que o & do c#. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type 'BigInteger'

Comment: Agora sim , Obrigado!

Answer (score 8):

Se você quer o [*bitwise* tem o operador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.op_bitwiseand?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Se quer o booleano, ele não precisa ter mesmo já que a operação independe de ser `int`, `BigInteger` ou outra coisa.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Numerics;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(VerificaPermissao((BigInteger)1, (BigInteger)0));
        WriteLine(VerificaPermissao((BigInteger)1, (BigInteger)1));
        WriteLine(VerificaPermissao((BigInteger)2, (BigInteger)1));
    }
    public static bool VerificaPermissao(BigInteger perm1, BigInteger perm) => (perm & perm1) != 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6v6TLO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w3hH9O). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/AndBigInteger.cs).

Aproveitei e simplifiquei já que `BigInteger` em C# é um tipo por valor e possui operadores para todas operações matemáticas básicas. Este código é mais [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101) em C#.

Quem quiser [comparar que o resultado é o mesmo em Java](http://ideone.com/w6PozE).

Comment: isso eu queria o bitwise!

Comment: @Bertuzzi editei a pergunta simplificando o código, em C# é mais fácil que Java. E fica mais rápido.