# Sutilezas entre Python e C

Tags: c, python

Boa noite! Domingo descobri que obrigatoriamente terei que aprender python, que a matéria que irei cursar será em nessa linguagem e não tem como fugir. Estudei bem essa semana e consegui chegar até matrizes, porém me deparei com sutilezas que ainda estou tentando compreender. Um dos exercícios que fiz hoje pedia que fizesse uma função que retornava se determinado objeto pertencia ou não a uma lista, fiz "duas" funções que seguem:

```
def Pertence1 (item, lista):
    return item in lista

def Pertence2 (item, lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if (item == lista[i]): return True
    return False
```

Essa segunda função foi a primeira que pensei, como tenho como linguagem "mãe" C, (se não fizer uma função que percorra uma lista (vetor), tenho até coceira), veio quase que automático imaginar um laço que percorre uma lista e compara item a item até encontrar, num segundo momento veio a primeira função, que sinto que não é exatamente uma "função" (ainda estou compreendendo esse conceito em python), mais simples, objetiva, cumpria o que o exercício pedia, porém achei de certa forma, muito simples e até obscura, pensando num código imenso entendo quanto seria mais útil a primeira. Não sei se com C apreendi que um bom código, consistente, precisa ser robusto, duro, com ponteiros kkk. Fazendo analogia entre o inglês e o português, sinto que se o requisito pra aprender outra língua fosse apenas vocabulário, bastaria decorar as palavras e pronto, mas não é bem assim, há sutilezas epistemológicas entre descrever o mesmo objeto em duas línguas, mesmo que a lógica seja a mesma pra descrever. Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre.

Comment: Nem vou usar o espaço da resposta pq, como vc mesmo diz, no final da pergunta, as respostas serão baseadas em opinião e eu prefiro não arriscar a estar fora do escopo do site, mas minha opinião é que, ao contrário do que vc acha, a primeira é muito mais elegante e, mais importante, mais pythonica.

Comment: E sim, isso não é opnião, na primeira função a lista é, tb, "percorrida" até encontrar o elemento (pq percorrer tudo?).
Se vc acha que a primeira é deselegante pq é muito simples, sugiro que abra um terminal do pyton e digite: `import this <enter>`, leia com bastante atenção e se apaixone pelo python. :-)

Comment: Creio que entendendo if, for, while, funções básicas e variáveis você já terá o básico, comparar ambas linguagens você não vai chegar a lugar algum, o que precisa aprender (por mais que você acredite já dominar) é a lógica de programação e a linguagem python, comparar com C só vai lhe atrapalhar mais.

Comment: @Sidon Acho que me expressei errado ao classificar como deselegante, no fundo queria falar que é obscuro, tipo, qual o tempo de execução dessa chamada? Ela se comporta da mesma forma com listas ordenadas? Ainda não conheço o funcionamento dessas "funções" intrínseca, vou seguir seu conselho e ler o que propôs.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como minha única referência em programação é C, acho que foi meio inevitável não comparar, por isso tentei levantar essa questão já pra evitar achar que C é melhor que Python e vice-versa, acho que nem faz sentido esse questionamento. foi um choque encontrar essa chamada de persistência em que eu não precise escrever um trecho de código que faça algo exaustivamente.

Comment: `Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre.` Não. Nó somos moralmente obrigados a fechar toda pergunta que peça opiniões.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você descreve é o que chamamos de código idiomático.

[O que é "expressão idiomática" na programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/5878)

Obviamente que haverá várias maneiras de se criar uma função que retorne o resultado desejado, mas nem todas elas serão idiomáticas; isto é, nem todas aplicarão a filosofia que a linguagem prega. Em C, faz sentido você ter que percorrer a lista até encontrar o valor desejado; ele foi desenvolvido para ser assim e funciona muito bem. O Python, por sua vez, prega que o código deve ler o mais legível a humanos; você escreve seu programa quase como se escrevesse um texto. Não tem como comparar as soluções em linguagens distintas e muito menos eleger qual é melhor. Ainda, em Python, as soluções idiomáticas nós chamamos de *pythonicas*.

[O que é um código "pythônico"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)

Agora, respondendo a sua pergunta, com certeza, em Python, a primeira solução faz muito mais sentido que a segunda. *Simple is better than complex.* Se há uma maneira simples, para quê complicar? E ainda digo que se não fosse como uma proposta de exercício nem faria sentido você definir uma função para executar essa lógica. Ficaria muito mais simples e legível você usar diretamente a condição `value in list` do que precisar chamar uma função para isso. *Readability counts.*