# Apresentar matriz em python

Tags: python, matriz

Eu tenho uma matriz de n por n e uso esta parte do código para a apresentar:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        print ((data[i][j]))
```

Sendo `data` a matriz. Mas o output fica desse jeito:

```
 5
 4
 1
10
 2
 3
 0
 2
 1
...
```

Os valores de `data` estão vindo daqui

```
    data = [ [-1 for i in range(vertice)] for j in range(vertice)]
    for i in range(vertice):
        for j in range(vertice):
            if data[i][j] < 0:
                data[i][j] = random.randint(0, vertice)
                data[j][i] = random.randint(0, vertice)
            if i == j:
                data[i][i] = 0

    return data
```

gostaria de apresentar desse jeito:

```
5 4 1 10 2
3 0 2  1 7 
3 0 2  1 7 
3 0 2  1 7
```

Já tentei de mil e uma maneiras, mas não estou chegando lá. Que estou a fazer de errado?

Comment: E que valores tem em `data`?

Comment: atribuo valores random. Ele apresenta sempre, por isso acho que é desta parte de código o erro

Comment: E como vamos saber o que tem de errado? Pra mim está tudo certo dada as informações passadas. Aí tem dados aleatórios sendo mostrados direitinho.

Comment: é o print que está errado, mas eu coloco o que deseja

Comment: E como deveria ser a saída do print?

Comment: pois, convém dizer. Sry.

Comment: na forma de matriz, identico pelo menos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, nunca percorra uma lista em Python com `for i in range(len(data))` para depois fazer `data[i]`. Isso não é [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/5878) ([pythonico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878)). Você pode fazer simplesmente um `for linha in data`.

```
data = [
    [5, 4, 1, 10, 2],
    [3, 0, 2,  1, 7],
    [3, 0, 2,  1, 7],
    [3, 0, 2,  1, 7]
]

for linha in data:
    for numero in linha:
        print(numero, end=" ")
    print()
```

O problema é que por o 10 possuir mais caracteres que os outros, a saída será:

```
5 4 1 10 2 
3 0 2 1 7 
3 0 2 1 7 
3 0 2 1 7
```

Você pode contornar isso formatando a saída:

```
for linha in data:
    for numero in linha:
        print(f'{numero:>3}', end=" ")
    print()
```

Perceba que ao invés de exibir apenas `numero` eu exibi `{numero:>3}`. Isso fará com que sempre seja exibido 3 caracteres e o número estará alinhado a direita:

```
  5   4   1  10   2 
  3   0   2   1   7 
  3   0   2   1   7 
  3   0   2   1   7
```

Resolve o problema para o 10, mas e se na matriz houver o número 9999? Isso eu deixo para você resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer exibir a matriz de uma maneira que seja mais amigável, separando em linhas em colunas, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
       print ((data[i][j]), end=" ")
    print()
```

o `Python` por padrão, adiciona uma quebra de linha no final do print, por isso para as linhas o parâmetro `end` para atribuir um espaço, ao invés e uma quebra de linha, já, o outro print tem a função de quebrar a linha sempre que uma linha da matriz for exibida totalmente.

Saída:

```
0 1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 6 
3 4 5 6 7 
4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: É isso, mesmo. Obrigado Junior Nascimento