# Criar lista com mais de um elemento como se fosse multidimensional

Tags: c#, .net, lista

Preciso receber esses pares de dados do banco, e estou pensando numa forma de como trazer os valores sem precisar criar um objeto, pois acho desnecessário nesse caso.

[image: Dados a serem importados]

É possível criar uma `list<string,string>` ou algo do tipo? de forma que eu possa acessar `list[0].value1` e `list[0].value2`. Sei que existe o `Dictionary`, mas não é a solução que eu estou procurando.

Comment: usar uma `List<dynamic>` não resolveria?

Comment: Mas como eu traria pares de string dentro dela? se for através de objetos com atributos SÓ PARA ISSO, não iria solucionar o problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é Tuple e quando usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94882/o-que-%c3%a9-tuple-e-quando-usar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As duas soluções apresentadas são ruins, uma cria uma classe de classe e aloca como louca sendo ineficiente em memória e processamento e outra torna o elemento como um dicionário que não tem a mesma semântica de uma lista de listas, ou mesmo o que deseja, pelo que está falando, até porque o que quer é uma lista de objetos e não de listas.

A solução adequada para o que quer (pelo que demonstrou e não pelo que falou) tem chance de ser a criação de uma `struct` que cuide disso, algo assim:

```
struct Item { public string AdminId, public string GroupId }
var lista = new List<Item>() { new Item { var1, var2 }, };
```

Usei o nome `Item` porque não sei do que isso se trata, deveria ser um nome melhor. Fiz de forma bem simplificada, provavelmente seria melhor fazer algo mais completo que isso por várias razões.

Por outro lado isso pode ser mesmo algo fugaz e não deveria criar um tipo para administrar isso, o que eu só poderia saber se tivesse mais detalhes da aplicação. Aí uma tupla seria mais adequada, mas seria a tupla moderna do C# 7. Algo assim:

```
var lista = new List<(string AdminId, string GroupId)>() { (var1, var2), };
```

Esse `var1` e `var2` são variáveis locais com o conteúdo, não precisa ser bem isso, se a pergunta tivesse o código ara criar eu faria um exemplo mais detalhado. Aproveitei para mostrar como se inicializa o código, e claro teria que usar vários itens. Pode ser que seja mais interessante inicializar depois em um laço:

```
foreach (var item in fonteDeDados) lista.Add((item.AdminId, item.GroupId));
```

Ou usando a estrutura:

```
foreach (var item in fonteDeDados) lista.Add(new Item() { item.AdminId, item.GroupId });
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AddItems.cs).

Claro, que estou considerando que a fonte de dados que montará sua lista vem de um objeto que tem os campos ou propriedades com os nomes que usei.

Comment: da uma olhada no titulo, resolvi não editar de volta, acho que você se confundiu.

Comment: Diz a falta de uma letra ou outra coisa? Mas pode arrumar, a pergunta é sua, só dei uma melhorada pra indicar melhor o que é, tava muito pobrinho

Comment: @Maniero acabei respondendo a minha, vi que já tem um exemplo sua : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94882/o-que-é-tuple-e-quando-usar

Comment: Não é repetida ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda achei que não porque é uma aplicabilidade específica, você achou?

Comment: @Maniero eu acho que sim, porque já tem as respostas como `Tuple` e `Dictionary` as duas fazem mesma coisa que o *Leonardo* quer, porem ele não soube fazer com `Dictionary`. Então acaba dando as respostas como `Tuples`.

Answer (score 6):

Pela sua descrição você desejaria utilizar a estrutura `Tuple<T1, T2>`, vou deixar abaixo um exemplo do que você descreveu que precisa:

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> tupla = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

tupla.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("valor1", "valor2"));
tupla.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("valor3", "valor4"));

//Acessando o primeiro item da lista
string item1 = tupla[0].Item1;
string item2 = tupla[0].Item2;
```

Comment: Depois de postar lembrei da classe `Tuple` acho que resolve, vou testar e ver como fica !

Answer (score 1):

Se calhar o mais viável para criar uma lista será o `Dictionary<string, string>`, que cria uma lista de `KeyValuePair`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var item in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine($"Key = {item.Key}, Value = {item.Value}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara gosto muito da classe `Tuple`, veja o exemplo:

```
//Definindo o valor com a inicialização de coleção simplificada
List<(string ADMIN_ID, string USER_GROUP_ID)> tuples = new List<(string, string)>
{
    ("3984", "3985"),
    ("3599", "3773")
};

//Outra forma de definir o valor
List<(string ADMIN_ID, string USER_GROUP_ID)> tuples1 = new List<(string, string)>();
tuples1.Add(("3984", "3985"));
tuples1.Add(("3599", "3773"));

//Obtendo o valor
string item1 = tuples.ElementAt(0).ADMIN_ID; //ou tuples[0].ADMIN_ID;
string item2 = tuples.ElementAt(0).USER_GROUP_ID; // ou tuples[0].USER_GROUP_ID;

//Outra forma de obter o valor
(string ADMIN_ID, string USER_GROUP_ID ) = tuples.ElementAt(0); // ou tuples[0];
```

*Fonte*: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tuples

*Nuget*: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/

> Lembrando que a versão do **C#** tem que ser ***7.0***  pra cima.