# Erro ao concatenar string de um path

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, windows, console-application

Nesse programa logo no começo tem uma função que cria uma pasta nos documentos do usuário para guardar umas informações

Dando uma pesquisada cheguei a conclusão que deveria fica assim:

```
    static int PrepararTerreno()
    {
        string Diretorio = ("C://Users//{0}//Documents//Cadastro",Environment.UserName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory (Diretorio);
        return 0;
    }
```

É para o programa ver o nome do usuário e inserir ali no meio da `string` para a pasta ser criada nos documentos do usuário que abri o programa.

Mas quando eu rodo o programa o Visual studio da esse erro:

> CS0029 Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "(string, string UserName)" em "string"

Comment: `String.Format("C://Users//{0}//Documents//Cadastro",Environment.UserName);`

Comment: Obrigado cara isso tava me dando uma dor de cabeça

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Esta função é um pouco esquisita. Se está praticando então seria interessante praticar o que é mais importante e ao mesmo tempo mais fácil porque nem é programação em si. Se pratica o erro é assim que fará sempre.

O nome da função não é boa porque não diz o que ela realmente faz. A não ser que ela faça algo que ainda não está no código, mas neste caso um comentário cairia bem, comentários servem justamente para isso.

O mesmo vale para o retorno, se vai retornar algo que é fixo, então é melhor retornar nada, a não ser que vá fazer outras coisas depois, e novamente um comentário cairia bem.

Não faz sentido usar `//` no texto, ou usa `\\` ou usa `/`. A `\\` é necessária porque a barra sozinha é um caractere de escape já que a barra invertida é usada para formatação. Se usar a barra invertida pode [usar o `@` para não precisar duplicá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101).

Pode usar [interpolação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101) aí e evitar maiores dores de cabeça.

O erro é que está criando uma tupla ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207800/101), [outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14532/101), [mais um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101), [o último](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321957/101)) composta por um objeto `string` e outro objeto `string` com um nome. E declarou uma variável do tipo `string` apenas (que obviamente não é uma tupla, fica incompatível).

A declaração está correta, a atribuição é que está errada. Os parênteses sobrando ali fazem toda diferença por criar um tipo diferente, por isso sempre falo:

[image: Enquanto você não souber o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar]

Até o espaço no nome da função é desnecessário, não dá erro, mas dá uma indicação errada, fica parecendo que está agrupando expressões ou criando uma tupla em vez de usar uma função. Parece bobagem mas o código fica menos legível. Mesmo que funcione nem tudo está certo, acostume-se fazer o certo e não apenas funcionar. Os piores erros são aqueles que o compilador não reclama.

E a variável nem é necessária.

Ficaria melhor assim:

```
static void PrepararTerreno() => Directory.CreateDirectory($"C:/Users/{Environment.UserName}/Documents/Cadastro");
```

Ou

```
static void PrepararTerreno() => Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\Documents\Cadastro");
```

Ou ainda

```
static void PrepararTerreno() => Directory.CreateDirectory($"C:\\Users\\{Environment.UserName}\\Documents\\Cadastro");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ConcatPath.cs).

Comment: Eu nunca me canso de ler as suas respostas. um grande fã como sempre kk

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação e pelos conselhos companheiro,ajudou muito

Comment: @LeonardoLopes você pode ver no [tour] o melhor jeito de dizer obrigado. Note que pode votar em todas respostas que quiser no site inteiro, mas só pode aceitar **uma** resposta em uma pergunta que você fez. Analise as duas e veja se uma delas merece uma aceitação. Em geral é bom que uma seja aceita, não a escolha é sua do que é melhor para você.

Answer (score 1):

**Sobre o Erro CS0029**:

> O compilador requer uma conversão explícita. Por exemplo, pode ser
>   necessário converter um valor r para o mesmo tipo que um valor l. Ou,
>   você deve fornecer rotinas de conversão para suportar certas
>   sobrecargas do operador.

Você precisa dizer para o compilador que você quer aquela saída de uma forma específica, neste caso no formato de string.

Você poderia fazer como o @Augusto Vasques citou no comentário usando o `string.Format`:

```
string diretorio = string.Format("C://Users//{0}//Documents//Cadastro", Environment.UserName);
```

ou usando o `string.Concat`:

```
string diretorio = string.Concat("C://Users//", Environment.UserName, "//Documents//Cadastro");
```

Existem várias maneiras de construir uma string, então caso queira mais definições sobre **`concatenação de string`** você pode ter um resumo rápido em [Qual o meio mais apropriado para se concatenar strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124/qual-o-meio-mais-apropriado-para-se-concatenar-strings) aqui no fórum ou consultar a [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings).