# Tuple é a mesma coisa que criar um objeto?

Tags: c#, .net, tupla, tuple

Já usei o [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) algumas vezes e hoje veio a dúvida, isso:

```
public class User{
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public String LastName {get; set;}
}

new User(){
    Name = "Leonardo",
    LastName = "Bonetti"
}
```

É a mesma coisa que isso?

```
new Tuple<String,String >("Leonardo", "Bonetti")
```

Estou com essa dúvida pois parece que sim, porém de forma menos organizada pois não há nome para os atributos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Estritamente falando, sim, é a mesma coisa. Afinal toda tupla é um [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), assim como todos os dados em C#.

Porém esse `Tuple` que está usando já é considerado (praticamente) obsoleto. Se quiser saber mais sobre ele: [O que é Tuple e quando usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94882/101).

Hoje é muito mais comum usar a [tupla da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101), que inclusive tem nomes para os campos (e [não atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) igual a um tipo, e diferente de `Tuple` que até tem nomes, mas genéricos (`Item1`, `Item2`, etc.). Esta tem muito mais vantagens de performance, semântica, ferramentas e maneiras de usar. Isso não quer dizer que a forma antiga não tenha algum motivo para uso, mas é bem difícil que aconteça, e se a classe `Tuple` ainda seria uma vantagem provavelmente tem uma outra forma de fazer.

Claro que criar uma classe (e aí não estamos falando de objeto), não é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas é parecido. [A classe permitirá você usá-la como modelo para criar objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101) desse tipo (uma classe cria um tipo na sua aplicação) e claro, ele terá um nome. É muito mais vantajoso usar uma classe para o seu exemplo (pelo menos sem ver maior contexto), `User` será um objeto que usado em toda aplicação, não tem porque usar um objeto que podemos dizer que é anônimo e sem um modelo claro. Vira bagunça, cada momento você poderá fazer um usuário diferente, e nem saberá o que é aquilo, porque o tipo do objeto criado com o mecanismo de tupla é um `Tuple` (no mais antigo).

`Tuple` foi criada para algo bastante específico, para transportar mais de um dado, que tem alguma relação naquele momento, como um objeto único. Ela foi criada principalmente para retornar mais de um valor por um método que só aceita retornar um valor. Ou seja, é para construí-la colocando objetos dentro dela, e pegar esses objetos do outro lado e acabou.

Só que isso gera alocação, a linguagem não sabe o que é isso, é uma classe como outra qualquer, e fica complicado para ferramentas trabalhar com ela, é algo genérico demais, é só um pouquinho melhor que fazer um `List<object>`. Por isso para esses casos onde uma tupla (vasilha) é útil passou se usar um `(objeto1, objeto2)` que trabalha na *stack*, não pressionando o *garbage collector*, a linguagem entende o que ela faz e pode ser usada de várias formas, é mais intuitivo, o Visual Studio te ajuda com Intelisense, afinal os nomes dos campos são visíveis, entre outras vantagens.

Mesmo essa nova forma é inadequada para substituir a sua classe `User`, alias é até pior porque a semântica dessa classe é por referência e a tupla é por valor. E isso é bom, mostra como são mecanismos muito diferentes pra propósitos completamente diferentes. A tupla é um mecanismo da sua aplicação, a classe pode até ser isso, mas muitas vezes, e no exemplo específico é, um modelo para um objeto de domínio, ou seja, tem a ver com o problema que você está resolvendo.

Jamais use uma tupla para substituir um tipo útil para a aplicação. Tupla é só para juntar objetos que precisam estar juntos naquele momento e não para representar um objeto geral da aplicação, então nesse ponto são totalmente diferentes.

Conhece método anônimo? É mais parecido com isso e sinceramente acho que a linguagem nunca deveria ter criado esse mecanismo (método anônimo), assim como a biblioteca não deveria ter `Tuple`, a tupla simples é a solução para esses casos.

Uma tupla não pode ser confundida como substituta de um tipo específico, ainda que ela seja um tipo geral.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, vou dar um exemplo só para ver se eu entendi direito o conceito e a sua recomendação, analisando a tabela dessa imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSuts.png são 2 ID's de 2 usuários diferentes(ou seja objeto `User`), eu preciso retornar APENAS esses dois ID's relacionados, eu posso tanto criar um objeto `RelacaoUser` com os dois atributos ou posso usar o `Tuple` para ligar os dois objetos em um só. De acordo com a sua resposta o melhor seria utilizar o `Tuple<User,User>` carregando o ID dentro de cada objeto `User` correto?

Comment: Na outra pergunta sobre o assunto que eu só vi depois eu acho que respondi isso, não? Eu não fui claro para não usar `Tuple`?

Comment: Sim, depois de comentar você respondeu lá. Obrigado !

Answer (score 5):

Pessoalmente acho que os `Tuple` devem ser utilizados quando precisamos simplificar algo no código, um trecho que precisa de uma validação estrutural simples, com `Item1` + `Item2` onde não precisamos obrigatoriamente de saber qual o significado do que está em cada um dos elementos, para além de ser muito mais restritivo do que uma `Class`.

`Tuple` é bem mais simples de implementar em relação às classes, é mais *lightweight*, mas devemos utilizar o senso comum para perceber onde deveremos utilizar um ou outro.

Uma classe é algo mais significativo e bem mais amplo, devemos utilizar quando for importante sabermos o que a propriedade `X` ou `Y` representa e em que circunstâncias devem ser utilizadas.

Em suma, tudo depende da utilização que vamos dar ao objeto, penso que será algo a analisar caso a caso.

Existem boas respostas nesta questão do **StackOverflow** "global", dê uma olhada! *[When to use: Tuple vs Class c# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650636/when-to-use-tuple-vs-class-c-sharp-7-0)*