# Passagem de parâmetros usando primitivos ou um objeto contendo os campos?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, método, objetos, parâmetros

Ao se criar a assinatura de um método, qual seria a melhor opção de design para a passagem de parâmetros?

Existe alguma boa prática que aborda a assinatura de métodos?

O que seria melhor? Para cada parâmetro os tipos simples que representem o mais sucinto possível cada dado passado, ou utilizar um objeto contendo os campos com cada dado que precise ser tratado dentro do método?

Exemplos

(cada parâmetro uma variável):

```
void inserir(string nome, int idade, string apelido, date dataDeNascimento)
```

(cada parâmetro um campo do objeto):

```
void inserir(Cliente cliente)
```

onde Cliente é uma classe:

```
class Cliente {  
  string nome;  
  int idade;  
  string apelido;  
  date dataDeNascimento;  
}
```

Comment: o mais adequado seria utilizar **void inserir(Cliente cliente)** que assim você usa os recursos da orientação a objetos e fica mais fácil de resolver possíveis problemas

Comment: @LuanBrito pode sustentar e fundamentar isso? Por que deve usar recursos de OO, e por que é mais fácil resolver possíveis problemas?

Comment: @LuanBrito, eu fiz a pergunta para avaliar as visões que muitos possam agregar, mas a minha é que não vejo vantagem alguma em utilizar um objeto, gostaria que alguém conseguisse me convencer se há algum cenário em que isso possa valer a pena. Usando o objeto na verdade você perde em muito com a OO, o método perdeu a assinatura com isso, quais serão os dados que ele irá tratar? você não sabe, só sabe que vai utilizar um objeto Cliente que pode ter centenas de campos, o que é verdade em aplicações grandes.

Comment: entendi seu ponto de vista, mas creio que não tenho argumentos suficientes para te convencer ao contrario

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mais uma vez repito aqui no SOpt: não existe isso de melhor opção, de boa prática, existe o que é o mais adequado no caso específico. Boa prática é a muleta que as pessoas usam para poder seguir receita de bolo sem aprender o fundamento do que está fazendo e tomar decisões corretas.

Outra coisa que falo muito é que um exemplo artificial é ruim porque não é um caso concreto e se você disser que é bom tal coisa pra esse caso ele não servirá para um caso real. O exemplo da pergunta é bem ruim porque ele não detalhe as condições reais do sistema (as pessoas falham muito porque nem percebem o que importa no que está fazendo) e é algo ingênuo.

Em geral criar um tipo só para criar um objeto e preencher com dados e usá-lo para passar como argumento (não se passa parâmetros) não faz o menor sentido. Mas não é uma regra absoluta.

Em geral se você tem um tipo criado e é fácil criar um objeto com ele, e faz sentido criá-lo ali, se naquele ponto esse objeto pode ser criado em estado válido e não tem outros problemas, então deveria aceitar o objeto, mas é comum ser um erro se tiver que criar o objeto só para passar como argumento, o ideal seria já ter esse objeto.

Para tudo tem exceção. E tem casos que deveria aceitar os dois jeitos, não dá para saber.

Esse exemplo parece ruim porque parece que esse tipo foi criado só para passar um objeto e não porque ele importa no sistema. Não que não possa criar tipos só para um mecanismo, mas é mais comum os tipos fazerem parte de um modelo e não só para resolver um problema do código.

Algo que poucas pessoas percebem é que a passagem de argumentos em uma chamada de função é uma [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321968/101) implícita (em alguns casos é até uma lista) e tuplas existem fundamentalmente para agrupar dados que fazem sentido estarem juntos em um contexto sem que seja preciso criar um tipo nominado, a tupla é um tipo anônimo, e a chamada da função tem dois tipos, o de entrada e o de saída, sendo que o de saída costuma ser único, mas pode ser múltiplo se você [retornar uma tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101), a entrada já é uma tupla sempre, com zero, um ou mais membros. Se fosse ensinado assim as pessoas entenderiam muita coisa melhor.

Só tenha em mente que a regra pela regra sempre é um erro. O correto é entender [o que faz algo ser coeso e o que permite o baixo acoplamento de forma pragmática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Comment: mas em regra geral não é bem melhor passar cada dado como um parâmetro na assinatura do método? assim estará tornando a interface explícita. mesmo que o objeto importe ao sistema e seja um objeto de domínio, a assinatura do método não perde sua semântica?

Comment: Quando fala em semântica não pode aplicar regra geral, cada caso tem sua semântica e só vendo o caso pode-se dizer qual é a melhor semântica ali. Se a pessoa não entender o que é semântica e qual é a semântica correta ela usará o mecanismo errado. Por isso eu falo que desenvolver não é decorar sintaxe de linguagem, é entender problemas.

Comment: é que eu tentei aplicar uma regra "geral" utilizada no mercado e ensinada nas universidades, em que se cria a entidade de domínio anêmico "Cliente" e ela é usada em todo lugar com centenas de campos, por isso que entendo que se perde a semântica, mas entendi tua ótima resposta que como sempre, mais uma vez agregou muito.