# Retorno de array em C#

Tags: c#, array, funções, procedure

Quando atribuo uma função que retorna um array a outro array, não tenho os valores correspondentes de cada índice como atribuídos dentro da função.

Preciso retornar três percentuais que sejam armazenados na variável da função main, e utilizá-las na procedure para imprimir os percentuais. Porém só tenho o retorno do valor 0, e não do percentual.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
using System;

namespace poo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numEleitores, numVotosVal, numVotosBran, numVotosNul;
            int[] percentuaisRetornados;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de eleitores: ");
            numEleitores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de votos válidos: ");
            numVotosVal = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de votos brancos: ");
            numVotosBran = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de votos nulos: ");
            numVotosNul = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            percentuaisRetornados = calculoPercentualVotos(numEleitores, numVotosVal, numVotosBran, numVotosNul);
            imprimirPercentuais(percentuaisRetornados, numEleitores);
        }

        static int[] calculoPercentualVotos(int qtdEleitores, int qtdVotosVal, int qtdVotosBran, int qtdVotosNul)
        {
            /**
            * Votos válidos: índice 0;
            * Votos brancos: índice 1;
            * Votos nulos: índice 2;
            */
            int[] percentuaisVotos = new int[3];

            percentuaisVotos[0] = (qtdVotosVal/qtdEleitores) * 100;
            percentuaisVotos[1] = (qtdVotosBran/qtdEleitores) * 100;
            percentuaisVotos[2] = (qtdVotosNul/qtdEleitores) * 100;

            return percentuaisVotos;
        }

        static void imprimirPercentuais(int[] percentArgs, int totalEleitores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"O total de eleitores é de: {totalEleitores}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Percentual de votos válidos: {percentArgs[0]}%");
            Console.WriteLine($"Percentual de votos brancos: {percentArgs[1]}%");
            Console.WriteLine($"Percentual de votos nulos: {percentArgs[2]}%");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Retorna uma [tupla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321968/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101)) em vez de retornar um *array*, é melhor por diversas razões, inclusive não ter quefazer comentário por ter usado a ferramenta errada. Não resolverá todos os erros do código, mas já fica melhor e resolve o problema relatado (na verdade nem sei se ele ocorre de fato, eu acho que só tem um problema de matemática por usar um inteiro em um valor que provavelmente dá parte decimal.